# Read 1 line per file descriptor using static nodes

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, file-descriptor

I'm trying to read a file one line at a time, with different buffer lengths. I am passing a file desc to the get_next_line function and assigning that line to a pointer. The problem is either when the buffer length is long, sometimes it prints the rest of the file and when I pass 2 different file descriptors I get a segfault. I'm thinking it has to do with saving the string in the node and finding that same node if fd is the same.
I'm not seeing where I'm doing something wrong here.

get_next_line.c

```
#include "get_next_line.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 ** CREATE THE NEXT NODE TO ADD TO THE LINKEDLIST.
 **
 */
t_node *create_node(char *buffer, int fd)
{
    int i;
    t_node *new;

    i = 0;
    while (*buffer != '\n')
        buffer++;
    if (*buffer == EOF)
        return 0;
    ++buffer;
    new = malloc(sizeof(t_node));
    new->fd = fd;
    new->next = NULL;
    new->str = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    while (buffer[i] != '\n')
    {
        new->str[i] = (char)malloc(sizeof(char));
        new->str[i] = buffer[i];
        i++;
    }
    return (new);
}

/*
 ** SEARCH THE LIST FOR FD AND GET THE OVERFLAP STRING FROM
 ** LAST READ.
 */
char *get_overlap(t_node **root, int fd)
{
    t_node *conductor;

    if (*root == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    conductor = *root;
    while (conductor->fd != fd && conductor != 0)
        conductor = conductor->next;
    if (conductor == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    return (conductor->str);
}

/*
 ** CALL THE CREATE NODE FUNCTION AND ADD IT TO THE  LINKEDLIST.
 **
 */
void save_overlap(char buffer[], t_node **root, int fd)
{
    t_node **conductor;
    t_node *new;

    new = create_node(buffer, fd);
    if (*root == NULL)
        *root = new;
    else
    {
        conductor = root;
        while (*conductor != NULL)
        {
            if ((*conductor)->fd == fd)
            {
                (*conductor)->str = new->str;
                break;
            }
            if ((*conductor)->next == NULL)
            {
                (*conductor)->next = new;
                break;
            }
            *conductor = (*conductor)->next;
        }
    }
}

/*
 ** PREPEND THE PREVIOUS OVERLAP IN BUFFER TO LINE STRING.
 **
 */
void prepend_overlap(char *str, char ***line, int *i)
{
    int b = *i;
    while (str[b])
    {
        (**line)[b] = (char)malloc(sizeof(char));
        (**line)[b] = str[b];
        b++;
    }
    *i = b;
}


/*
 ** GET A SINGLE LINE AT A TIME FROM A FILE
 ** WHILE ALSO KEEPING TRACK OF THE FD.
 */
int get_next_line(const int fd, char **line)
{
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE + 1];
    int i;
    int j;
    char *overlap_str;
    static t_node *root;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    overlap_str = get_overlap(&root, fd);
    if(overlap_str != NULL)
        prepend_overlap(overlap_str, &line, &i);
    read(fd, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
    while (buffer[j] != '\n')
    {
        if (j == BUFF_SIZE)
        {
            (*line)[i] = (char)malloc(sizeof(char));
            (*line)[i] = buffer[j];
            j = 0;
            read(fd, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
            continue;
        }
        (*line)[i] = (char)malloc(sizeof(char));
        (*line)[i] = buffer[j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    (*line)[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", *line);
    save_overlap(buffer, &root, fd);
    return (0);
}

int main()
{
    int fd = open("test", O_RDONLY);
    //int fdt = open("test2", O_RDONLY);
    char *line;

    get_next_line(fd, &line);
    get_next_line(fd, &line);

}
```

get_next_line.h

```
#ifndef GET_NEXT_LINE_H
# define GET_NEXT_LINE_H

# define BUFF_SIZE 32
#include <fcntl.h>

int get_next_line(const int fd, char **line);

typedef struct s_node
{
    int fd;
    char *str;
    struct s_node *next;
}t_node;

#endif
```

It works with a single file descriptor, for example I can pass just fd instead of fdt and it will work, except if I set the buffer size of 120 or above for example, then it will print more than I want. I only want the line before '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

```
new->str = malloc(sizeof(char *));
...
new->str[i] = (char)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do here. `malloc(N * sizeof(char*))` can be used to create an array of pointers to "character arrays", with size `N`. That basically "array of strings" or "a 2-dimensional character array".

`malloc(sizeof(char))` is simply `malloc(1)`, or just one byte. If `new->str` is a character array then `str[i]` is already one byte and it should not be set with `malloc`

Do this instead to allocate for a character array:

```
new->str = malloc(5);
strcpy(new->str, "1234");
```

This will allocate 5 bytes for `str`, then copy "1234" to it, and add a zero at the end, that's a total of 5 bytes.

Also your linked list doesn't have a head. Try the following code instead.

```
#include <stdlib.h>//*** don't forget the right header files
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_node
{
    char *str;
    struct s_node *next;
}t_node;

void insert_node(t_node** head, char* buf)
{
    t_node *node = malloc(sizeof(t_node));
    node->next = 0;

    //allocate memory for string and copy
    node->str = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1); //+1 for nul-terminator
    strcpy(node->str, buf);

    if (*head == 0)
    {
        *head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        //find the end of the linked list
        t_node *tail = *head;
        while (tail->next)
            tail = tail->next;

        //make the end element point to new node
        tail->next = node;
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fd = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (!fd)
    {
        printf("file error\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //linked list identifier:
    t_node *head = 0;

    char buf[1000];

    //read the file line by line
    while(fscanf(fd, "%999s", buf) > 0)
    {
        //insert line in to linked list
        insert_node(&head, buf);
    }

    //show the result of the linked list:
    t_node *walk = head;
    while (walk)
    {
        printf("[%s]\n", walk->str);
        walk = walk->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that if one or more line is more than 1000 characters long, then the above code will fail. You can increase the buffer length, or there are ways to deal with that, but I leave it as is to make the example simple.

Make sure compiler warning level is at 4 or maximum, and make sure you deal with all warnings and errors.

Comment: If I call get_next_line twice with two different fd, I have to find the node with that fd if it exists and replace the str. Also, my final solution should have a main without anything but file descriptor and a lline(string) pointer.

Comment: It looks like you are not interested in what I wrote. And you are not interested in compiler warnings which say "don't cast `void*` to `char`"

Comment: What compiler do you use? You should get a warning for this cast `new->str[i] = (char)malloc(sizeof(char))`. Use `malloc` the way I showed. Your linked list is also broken.

Comment: I did, but that's not the problem. Have you tried running it exactly the way my code was, you changed the main

Comment: I tried your code, it crashes in `get_next_line`, here: `(*line)[i] = (char)malloc(sizeof(char))`. In other places your code doesn't do anything or it's just wrong. A linked list must have a `head`. This is not optional. There should be a `head` like `t_node *head = 0;` in the code which I posted.

Comment: what about two different fd's?

Comment: i have to somehow have the head not in main but one of the other functions, i could make it static so i don't lose it between function calls

Comment: You can do that for example by creating a function `foo()`, and move everything from `main` to `foo`. Then in `main` you would call `foo()`. You can pass `head` between functions.